# Xamarin: Issues with transitioning between controllers and storyboard views

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I realize this might come across as a very basic question, but I just downloaded Xamarin three days ago, and I've been stuck on the same issue for two days without finding a solution.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Get user input, call API, parse JSON and pass data to another controller, and change views.

Here is what I have been able to do so far: I get the user input, I call the API, I parse the response back, write the token to a file, and I want to pass the remaining data to the second controller.

This is the code I am trying:

```
var verifyCode = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("verify") as VerifyCodeController;
if (verifyCode != null) 
{
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(verifyCode, true);
}
```

My storyboard setup:

Navigation controller -> routesTo -> FirstController

I have another UI Controller View set up with the following properties set: 
storyboardid: verify
restorationid: verify

and I am trying to push that controller view onto the navigation controller.

Right now this line is erroring out:

```
var verifyCode = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("verify") as VerifyCodeController;
```

giving me this error, which I don't know what it means: Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance.

Am I way off in my approach?

p.s: I cannot use the ctrl drag thing like the tutorial suggests because I have an asynchronous call. And I cannot under no circumstances make it synchronous. So all the page transition has to be manual.

**EDIT**

to anyone requesting more code or more info:

```
    partial void registerButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        phone = registrationNumber.Text;

        string url = url;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url); 
        request.Method = "GET"; 
        Console.WriteLine("Getting response...");
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {            
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            }
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                }
                else 
                { 
                    var json = JObject.Parse (content);
                    var token = json["token"];
                    var regCode = json["regCode"];
                    var aURL = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                    var filename = Path.Combine (aURL, "app.json");
                    File.WriteAllText(filename, "{token: '"+token+"'}");


                    // transition to main view. THIS IS WHERE EVERYTHING GETS MESSED UP
                    var verifyCode = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("verify") as VerifyCodeController;
                    if (verifyCode != null) 
                    {
                        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(verifyCode, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Here is all the info for every view in my storyboard:

1- Navigation controller:
   - App starts there
   - The root is the register pager, which is the page we are currently working on.

2- The register view.
   
- The root page
   
- class RegisterController
   
- No storyboard id
   
- No restoration id

3- The validate view
   
- Not connected to the navigation controller initially, but I want it to be connected eventually. Do I have to connect it either way? Through a segue?
   
- class VerifyCodeController
   
- storyboard id : verify
   
- restoration id : verify

If you guys need more information I'm willing to post more. I just think I posted everything relevant.

Comment: Can you post a sample somewhere?

Comment: @Blounty there is so much code, but I'll try to post more information. It's just frustrating because the documentation is a bit weak, and transitioning should be made to be a lot easier than it is.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can still use a standard Segue to navigate to the new view controller. If you are on a different thread to the UI then call InvokeOnMainThread(() => //do your Seque );

Comment: @Blounty I'll try to erase my code, and try a different approach using Segues. I'll let you know if it works :)